# How to list all the edges associated with a particular node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to use Cypher to get a list of all the relationships (incoming and outgoing) of a node.

For example, here we have 4 nodes and their associated relationships. I want to list all the relationships associated with the `APT28` node.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: What does your graph model look like?

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide enough information about your data model. So I will assume here that the node you are interested in has the label `Foo` and that the `APT28` value is in the `id` property.

To get all of the `APT28` node's outgoing and incoming relationships, simply use this query (notice that it uses an [undirected](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/patterns/#cypher-intro-patterns-relationship-syntax) relationship pattern):

```
MATCH (n:Foo {id: 'APT28'})-[r]-()
RETURN r
```